# Convergence of regression coefficients to probability density

Tags: regression, probability, mathematical-statistics

By simulation we create a vector $Y = (y_1,y_2,...,y_n)$, where each $y_i \in R$ is independently drawn from a given non-degenerate distribution.

Next we create by simulation a vector $\xi  = (\xi_1,\xi_2,...,\xi_n)$ where each $\xi_i$ are independent realizations of a random variable which takes only finite number of values $[\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...\alpha_k]$ with probabilities $p_1,p_2,...,p_k$ respectively. $\alpha_i$ are given.

Suppose that we have got function $f: R \to R$

We make a regression of$\begin{bmatrix}
    f(y_1+\xi_1)  \\
    f(y_2+\xi_2) \\
    ... \\
    f(y_n+\xi_n)     
\end{bmatrix}$ on $\begin{bmatrix}
    f(y_1+\alpha_1) & f(y_1+\alpha_2) &  ...& f(y_1+\alpha_k) \\
    f(y_2+\alpha_1) & f(y_2+\alpha_2) &  ... & f(y_2+\alpha_k)\\
    ...    & ...   &  ... & ... \\
    f(y_n+\alpha_1) & f(y_n+\alpha_2) &... & f(y_n+\alpha_k)
\end{bmatrix}$

By regression I mean that we are optimizing $\beta_i$  to minimize:

$\sum_{i=1}^n(f(Y+\xi)-\sum_{j=1}^k\beta_jf(Y+\alpha_j))^2$

Intuitively I think that as $n \to \infty$ least squares procedure should give us the following equation:

$f(Y + \xi) = p_1*f(Y+\alpha_1) + p_2*f(Y+\alpha_2) + ... +p_k*f(Y+\alpha_k)$

where $f(Y + \xi)$ and $f(Y+\alpha_i)$ are just representations of vector columns above.

So my conjecture is that as $n \to \infty, \beta_i \to p_i$.

My question is what conditions should be imposed on function $f$ to get the equation above? Maybe $f$ should be smooth enough etc.Is my intuition correct that normally we should get such a equation? Maybe we need to impose some conditions on the distribution of $y_i$ also like $y_i$ is bounded etc.